# Deploying a golang webserver made with fiber to an ubuntu server

Tags: go, ubuntu, nginx, go-fiber

I made a rest API using golang and Fiber. I have a VPS running Ubuntu. Right now I ssh into that server using vps.mydomain.com. I want to host the API I made on the Ubuntu server and I want to be able to access it using api.otherdomain.com. I do not want to have to specify the port every time I request the API. I have tried using nginx as a reverse proxy in front of the API however for some reason every time I do that, it doesn't work.

My question is, is there a way I can host the API on my server and access it with my domain without specifying the port whilst not using a reverse proxy, or do I have to use Nginx or an alternative for it to work? I know how to run the API on the server and I know how to set up the DNS but I don't know if I am configuring nginx wrong or what but it just doesn't want to work. Let me know, thanks!

Every time I set up Nginx it and made a request to the domain I thought I had set up, nothing happened and I don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there could be a misconfiguration causing your current situation. Providing code snippets to replicate the error could offer valuable insights for assistance.

For maintaining the continuous operation of your Go programming, you might want to explore using supervisord or systemd. Overlaying Nginx as a proxy server is also a recommended approach. The tutorial at https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-go-web-application-using-nginx-on-ubuntu-18-04 illustrates the deployment of a Go web application with systemd and Nginx. This resource can guide you through the process.

Alternatively, you can access the Go server directly by allocating ports 80 and 443.